# How to: Multilingual site with one front page that makes user choose a language first

Tags: i18n-l10n

I want to have a front page like www.mysite.com/frontpage that shows up for every new visitor and helps him select a language and then move on to whatever language homepage the user selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom block to display the language enable into site and a link to respective page of particular language.

To display the custom block in home page, you can use panels, create different template for the home page (page--front.tpl.php).

Answer (score -3):

Read https://drupal.org/documentation/multilingual

Install https://drupal.org/documentation/multilingual

One configured your site will have /es and /en,  for example. Simply add now a front end ui linking to each one and that's it :-)